# What is the difference between git - and git -- options?

Tags: git

I'm attempting to learn the git commands and noticed that  the single - options appear to be heavily used simple flags. Then the -- appear to be more verbose. Some of these options are the same, but others are not.

- Same: git commit -m "SomeText" and git commit --message="SomeText"
- No Single character flag option: git commit --amend

Is this because there are other single flags to use to get this? Are there any style guides? Is there anything else behind this?

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/387935/whats-the-difference-betwen-the-single-dash-and-double-dash-flags-on-shell-comm

Comment: For equivalent commands there is no difference. See `man git`, `man git-<subcommand>` / `git help <subcommand>`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+difference+dash+double-dash

Comment: Might i suggest instead of learning the commands, learn the model behind git so you understand how it works, the commands can then be derived from first principles. Recommend watching this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sevc6668cQ0